# Maximize two variables function subject to quadratic constraint

Tags: optimization, quadratics

Two mariners end up on a island, with 1800 pounds of food to share, i.e. $F1 + F2 = 1800$.

I'm expected to maximize the social welfare function given by $W=U1^{0.25}*U2^{0.75}$ where $U1=\sqrt{F1}$ and $U2=0.5\sqrt{F2}$

I tried to use the fact that W was a Cobb-Douglas function, but I found the constraint to be equal to $U1^{2}*4U2^{2}=1800$. Hence I don't know how to move on from there.

$MP1=(1/4)*(U2/U1)^{0.75}$ & $MP2=(3/4)*(U1/U2)^{0.25}$

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why don't you eliminate $F_2$ from the constraint and express everything as a function of $F_1$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. How would I get rid of $F2$ ?

Comment: $F_2=1800-F_1$. Now express $W$ as a function of $F_1$ only. I hope I properly understood the problem (in fact, I do not see any quadratic constraint).

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be approached using the method of Lagrange's multipliers. First, we express the welfare function through $F_1$ and $F_2$ as

$W(F_1,F_2) = \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{3/4}(F_1F_2^3)^{1/8}$.

Then, we can write the function to be maximized as

$L(F_1,F_2) = W(F_1,F_2) + \lambda(F_1+F_2-1800)$.

Next, we find partial derivatives

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial F_1} = \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{3/4}\frac{1}{8}(F_1^{-7}F_2^3)^{1/8} + \lambda= 0$;

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial F_2} = \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{3/4}\frac{3}{8}(F_1F_2^{-5})^{1/8} + \lambda = 0$;

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} = F_1+F_2 + 1800 = 0$.

Now, the first two equations yield, after eliminating $\lambda$

$F_2 = 3F_1$,

which, in combination with the last derivative, gives $F_1 = 450$ and $F_2 = 1350$.

Hope this helps.